# yii2 enable prettyurl cause Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, pretty-urls

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' =>
        [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
/*other codes*/
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

everything seems alright and run init to ensure set writable to your app
but still 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Check server logs to see what is wrong. Maybe there is no mod_rewrite installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that .htaccess is in the same folder with index.php
like this
index.php

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```